# java IllegalStateException when using StackLayoutPanel and StackPanel

Tags: java, gwt

I'm testing the GWT StackLayoutPanel class with this code

```
public class MenuView extends StackLayoutPanel {

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<StackLayoutPanel, MenuView> {
    }

    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField Users users;

    @UiField Configurations configurations;

    public MenuView(Unit unit) {
        super(unit);
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public int getVisibleIndex() {
        return super.getVisibleIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public Widget getVisibleWidget() {
        return super.getVisibleWidget();
    }
}


————————————————————————

public class Users extends Composite {

    /**
     * Callback when user items are selected.
     */
    public interface Listener {
        void onUserSelected(User user);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the listener that will be notified when an item is selected.
     */
    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Listener listener;

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, Users> {
    }

    interface Style extends CssResource {
        String item();
    }

    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    ComplexPanel panel;
    @UiField
    Style style;

    public Users() {
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
}

MenuView.ui.xml File
<ui:UiBinder
  <g:StackLayoutPanel styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'>
    <g:stack>
      <g:header size='3'><div class='{style.stackHeader}'><div class='{style.usersIcon}'/> Users</div></g:header>
      <sensport:Users ui:field='users'/>
    </g:stack>
  </g:StackLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>

user.ui.xml File
<ui:UiBinder>
  <g:FlowPanel styleName='{style.users}' ui:field='panel'/>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

When I running the test I obtain a java IllegalStateException. Have you on idea of this error ?

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Composite.initWidget() may only be called once.
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite.initWidget(Composite.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ResizeComposite.initWidget(ResizeComposite.java:30)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.MenuView.<init>(MenuView.java:26)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.build_menuView(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:122)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.get_menuView(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:118)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.build_f_SplitLayoutPanel2(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:106)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.get_f_SplitLayoutPanel2(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:100)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.build_f_DockLayoutPanel1(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:73)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.get_f_DockLayoutPanel1(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:66)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl$Widgets.access$0(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:65)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl.createAndBindUi(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:15)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport_BinderImpl.createAndBindUi(Sensport_BinderImpl.java:1)
    at be.lilab.sensport.client.Sensport.onModuleLoad(Sensport.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

You are extending StackLayoutpanel, which extends ResizeComposite.
In the constructor of the StackLayoutPanel, the method initWidget is called.

So, calling it again with:

```
public MenuView(Unit unit) {
    super(unit);
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
```

will cause the exception. In your case a possible solution will be, to extend Composite.

```
    public class MenuView extends Composite {

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<StackLayoutPanel, MenuView> {
    }

    private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField Users users;

    @UiField Configurations configurations;

    @UiField StackLayoutPanel panel;

    public MenuView(Unit unit) {
        super(unit);
        initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

    @Override
    public int getVisibleIndex() {
        return panel.getVisibleIndex();
    }

    @Override
    public Widget getVisibleWidget() {
        return panel.getVisibleWidget();
    }
}
```

update your MenuViewui.xml:

```
<ui:UiBinder
  <g:StackLayoutPanel ui:field='panel' styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'>
    <g:stack>
      <g:header size='3'><div class='{style.stackHeader}'><div class='{style.usersIcon}'/> Users</div></g:header>
      <sensport:Users ui:field='users'/>
    </g:stack>
  </g:StackLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Comment: Thanks El Hoss, when i change the code to extend Composite i loss the posibility of uses the methods getVisibleIndex and getVisibleWidget, are you somme idea for it?

Comment: Do you mean the StackLayoutPanel inside your ui.xml?

Comment: I need use the ui.xml like this :                           MenuView.ui.xml File
<ui:UiBinder
  <g:StackLayoutPanel styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'>
    <g:stack>
      <g:header size='3'><div class='{style.stackHeader}'><div class='{style.usersIcon}'/> Users</div></g:header>
      <sensport:Users ui:field='users'/>
    </g:stack>
  </g:StackLayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>

user.ui.xml File
<ui:UiBinder>
  <g:FlowPanel styleName='{style.users}' ui:field='panel'/>
</ui:UiBinder>

Comment: Do you need to know the visible index from the StackLayoutPanel of your ui.xml? This one:  <ui:UiBinder <g:StackLayoutPanel styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'>

Comment: Yes, the Visible index from the StackLayoutPanel

Comment: Thanks... does not work because for this sentences @UiField StackLayoutPanel panel; the Field panel has no corresponding field in template file MenuView.ui.xml. the Field panel is part of user.ui.xml user.ui.xml File
<ui:UiBinder>
  <g:FlowPanel styleName='{style.users}' ui:field='panel'/>
</ui:UiBinder>

Comment: You have fo change <g:StackLayoutPanel styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'> to <g:StackLayoutPanel ui:field='panel' styleName='{style.menuview}' unit='EM'>